# how to set cell setVerticalAlignment in poi word?

Tags: apache-poi

I want to set cell VerticalAlignment in poi word, but I found it doesn't work, this is my code. what's wrong with it?

```
XWPFTableCell cell = table.getRow(i).getCell(j);
cell.setVerticalAlignment(XWPFTableCell.XWPFVertAlign.CENTER);
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? It works for me. Is your cell more than one line tall? This only happens if you have another cell that is taller that the one that is centered.

Comment: take a screen clip of your result, and add it to the question

Comment: when  I open the word file, content's position seems to be not change,  but when the content selected I can see from word toolbar it works, what's wrong with this?

Comment: I do some test, if the cell height is very high, content will in vertical center, but if cell height become small, the content will seems to be top of cell.

Comment: Oh, I insert the content by paragraph block, and the paragraph have default after space, that is the reason, if I paragraph.setSpacingAfter(0), that will be ok !  Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You cant directly set the alignment of any cell. each and every cell contains a paragraph and they contains the runs. so you also need to set their alignments. I have achieved the same problem by following method. hope it will also solve yours. thumbs up :)**

```
private static void setHeaderRowforSingleCell(XWPFTableCell cell, String text) {
        XWPFParagraph tempParagraph = cell.getParagraphs().get(0);
        tempParagraph.setIndentationLeft(100);
        tempParagraph.setIndentationRight(100);
        tempParagraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
        XWPFRun tempRun = tempParagraph.createRun();
        tempRun.setFontSize(10);
        tempRun.setColor("FFFFFF");
        tempRun.setText(text);
        cell.setVerticalAlignment(XWPFVertAlign.CENTER);
    }
```